# How to make a popup to select an item using the Sonata lists

Tags: php, html, symfony, popup, sonata

I recently started a project using Symfony, and as a part of it, there is a Sonata (modeled) backoffice. I love the way Sonata make that lists of items where you can search / filter or wathever.. So, the question is:

**Can I reuse this lists as a popup for example to select a user of my DB?**

The example is easy:

- I have a user table on my DB
- I have a form where you can select a user in one input but, there is 10.000 in the DB so a select is not an option.
- I'd love to use the user list of my sonata project in a popup and when the client click on a user of the list I would put it on the base form.

Is that possible? Is there a way for that?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do that using sonata_type_model_list as your field type.

You can see some examples of it [here](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/doctrine-orm-admin/master/doc/reference/form_field_definition.html)

Note that for a large dataset this is pretty useless unless you add some filters to it as well, otherwise it's just a huge paginated list.

Comment: My point was doing it outside sonata to call it rhought an URL but thanks for trying, your answer help me in other issue ;)

Answer (score 0):

Finally I did it creating new Admins with this fields inside:

```
protected $baseRouteName = 'admin_product_clean_list';
protected $baseRoutePattern = 'product-clean';
```

I also override the getTemplate method to use my clean custom layout like this:

```
public function getTemplate($name)
{
    switch ($name) {
        case 'layout':
            return 'DemoBundle:admin:onlytable_layout.html.twig';
            break;
        default:
            return parent::getTemplate($name);
            break;
    }
}
```

An then just use it with URLs like this:

```
"{{ app.request.getBaseURL() }}/admin/product-clean/list"
```

Not sure if it is the best way but it works like a charm.. I can use my custom layout copied of sonata's project (vendor/sonata-project/admin-bundle/Resources/views/standard_layout.html.twig) and remove or add whatever I want. You can also use the sonata empty or ajax layouts instead.